# image view size in splash-screen

Tags: android, splash-screen

I'm creating a splash screen for my application but i have a problem:
I put the image in drawable does not occupy the entire screen of your smartphone.
how to solve?

it's my xml:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:gravity="fill"
      android:layout_gravity="center">

           <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/fundo" />

     </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to `ImageView`